# XMLHttpRequestでget通信の値を渡せないのか

Tags: javascript

私がやりたいことはget_ajax_text.phpの所にクエリストリングスを入れてgetで通信したいのですができますか？

テストコード作ってやってみましたが、その前の段階のget通信すらできませんでした。泣
content-typeを入れればpost通信できました。

まず、get通信が出来るか、出来るなら、クエリストリングスを入れて出来るのか教えてほしいです。

```
echo <<<HTML
<script>
var login;
var data = {login:1};
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('GET', './get_ajax_text.php', true);
//ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajax.send(EncodeHTMLForm2(data));

function EncodeHTMLForm2(data) {
    var params = [];
    for ( var name in data) {
        var value = data[name];
        var param = encodeURIComponent(name).replace(/%20/g, '+') + '='
                + encodeURIComponent(value).replace(/%20/g, '+');
        params.push(param);
    }
    return params.join('&');
}
</script>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
ajax.sendの引数にnullを入れて
./get_ajax_text.phpに
./get_ajax_text.php?login=1
にしたらgetで渡せました。皆様ありがとうございました。